# How can I update a UITableViewController since other View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings, tabbarcontroller

I am designing an application for iOS in `objective-C` and I am trying to implement a section of settings for my app. I use a `TabBarController`.

I have two measurements of weight and height, and I want that the user can select between kg and pounds for example, in the settings section.

I have an object called Person whose height and weight attributes. Then in a `UITableViewController` (contains in other Item of `TabBarController`) I show all Person in a `NSMutableArray` that contains multiple people.

Then when the user selects the preferred measure in settings, I don't know what I do or how I can do.

I'm using Storyboards and Settings are in a different item that the UITableView of Person.

Thank you!!

Comment: you need to relaod the table with new data rite?

Comment: Is it "expensive" to reload your table, say reload at `viewWillAppear:` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may change text of `UILable` to `kg` and `pounds` in your cell. And the second you may implement different cell prototypes on your `UITableView`.
And try to use this code:

```
NSArray* toUpdate = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:toUpdate withRowAnimation:NO];
```